# mkdir() created directory is seen as file

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I am trying to change names of my app's directories for users data. I change it in a code and delete it from phone to check if the app create new ones with right names. And then troubles begin. Directories are created but when I try to open directory in windows explorer, It is seen as a file. `mkdir()` return `true` for each directory.

When I check `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()` it return `true` too. My `gradle` configuration

```
  compileSdkVersion 23    
  minSdkVersion 23    
  targetSdkVersion 23
```

(I want to downgrade to minSdkVersion 21). In manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Some code (updated):

```
File appDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Trainer app/");
File modelsDir = new File(appDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Modele/");
File pdfDir = new File(appDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Ostatnio wygenerowany trening/");
boolean result;
if(!appDir.exists()){
Log.wtf("StorageState",""+Environment.getExternalStorageState()+" Write: "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite());
Log.wtf("TEST DIR","Create appDir "+result+" is dir: "+appDir.isDirectory());
Log.wtf("TEST DIR","Create appDir "+result);
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{appDir.toString()}, null, null);
}
//if(appDir.exists()&&!modelsDir.exists()){
if(!modelsDir.exists()){
//Log.wtf("MODELDIR", "" + modelsDir.mkdir() + " Path: " + modelsDir.getAbsolutePath());
result=modelsDir.mkdirs();
Log.wtf("TEST DIR", "Create modelDir "+result+" is dir: "+modelsDir.isDirectory());
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{modelsDir.toString()}, null, null);
}
//if(appDir.exists()&&!pdfDir.exists()){
if(!pdfDir.exists()){
//Log.wtf("PDFDIR", "" + pdfDir.mkdir() + " Path: " + pdfDir.getAbsolutePath());
result=pdfDir.mkdirs();
Log.wtf("TEST DIR","Create pdfDir "+result+" is dir: "+pdfDir.isDirectory());
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{pdfDir.toString()}, null, null);
}
```

UPDATE: now I have no right to write on external storage. When I change `minSdk` to 21 and `targetSdk` to 22 I have rights but I still can't create directories even using your tips

Comment: And is it seen as directory in JAVA ?

Comment: yes when i call `isDirectory()` it returns true

Comment: The update is more like a Permission problem. Check on how these works since api 23 and before (Different request)

Comment: thanks I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies right here

```
File appDir = new File (path,file_name);

File appDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Trainer app");
```

and this `appDir.mkdir()` will creates a file named `Trainer app` under the default path of storage directory

so you want to create directory like as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/Trainer app` then do it like this

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Trainer app/";

File dictionary = new File(path);
if (!dictionary.exists()) {
   dictionary.mkdirs();
}
```

To create a file later

```
File file1 = new File(dictionary, filename);
```

Update : You need to implement Run-Time permission model to gain the access from user to access storage , try this [link for implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: @matejko219 add runtime-permission model to app and problem solved, just google this

Comment: @matejko219 you can thank me by accepting my answer,one of the best way to say thanks on SO  :)

Comment: @matejko219 try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow and add it to your project

Comment: I quickly add this solution and after granting permission the folder is now created (permission problem solved) but still in windows explorer it is seen as a file

Comment: as it's clear , follow the same process to create new folders and problem solved